# Playing YouTube videos on slow internet connection

Tags: kodi

I'm using Raspberry Pi B+ model with XBMC (KODI) operating system.
I'm running on slow internet connection hence cannot stream 720p videos and buffering takes more time than playing the video.
Is there any way I can configure XBMC to run all YouTube videos at 240p / 360p (worst case).

Comment: You could always use youtube-dl...

Comment: What sorts of videos are they? If they are trailers I can point you in the direction of a script to download trailers. Otherwise, I would recommend youtube-dl and a script to grab everything from your youtube favourites.

Comment: They are normal videos - like songs / movies etc., I do not want to download them. I've downloaded youtube-dl - but it does not help me select 360p or 240p videos. That is what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

Even it is an old question, it should be answered for those who come from google.

**Set video quality/resolution**:

Yes, you can set the quality for all YouTube videos. Because you use the Add-on called YouTube, there is the possibility to configure some settings. Open the settings in the Add-on, just where you open your subcriptions, playlists, login/logout and so on.

In the general tab, you can set the highest video quality used (if an uploaded video has only lower quality available, the lower quality will be used):
[image: Youtube Add-on settings video quality]

Newer Versions of Kodi have the possibility to use MPEG-DASH. If activated, it will override the General settings. There you can achive 1080p with 60fps 
But I would not recommend it, if you only want lower quality. Can't even set it to lower than 480p.

**youtube-dl**:
In youtube-dl you can also select the video quality to download.

My internet connection is also very slow and so I download at night videos from my favorite channels and watch them later.

Configuration for quality selection is described here: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection

For example: `-f bestvideo[ext=mp4][height<=480]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]`

I can provide a complete bash script with configuration for youtube-dl if somebody needs one. With downloading thumbnails, delete old videos and embedding informations about the video from youtube in the video file, so Plex can parse them.